# Error Message on Flow Embedded in Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button, visual-workflow

I have a custom button that calls a visualforce page. In this VF page I embedded a flow in order to control the "finish location".
I got the following error message:

> unexpected token: ':'
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been
>   notified. (Flow__Interview)

Can you tell me why it happened and solve this? I added the VF and Apex code below.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="flowFinishContExt_Acct" tabStyle="Lead">
<!-- Checks for object accessibility -->
<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!$ObjectType.Lead.accessible}">
<flow:interview name="Deal_Registration_New" interview="{!FacLookupFlow}" buttonLocation="both" finishLocation="{!FinishPage}">
<apex:param name="VarLeadID" value="{!Lead.id}"/>
</flow:interview>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
  public class flowFinishContExt_Acct {
    private final Lead acct;
    //Uses Standard Lead Controller 
    public flowFinishContExt_Acct(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.acct = (Lead)stdController.getRecord();
    }

//Calls referenced Flow below
public Flow.Interview.Deal_Registration_New FacLookupFlow {get; set;}
//Gets Id of variables below from flow
public String getaccountID() {
if (FacLookupFlow==null) return '';
else return FacLookupFlow.VarLeadID;
}
//Used for Flow finish location
public PageReference getFinishPage(){

return new PageReference('/' + getaccountID());

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce have broken the `<flow:interview>` component in the run up the Winter '14 release.

They are aware of this but we have not been given a resolution ETA yet.

Comment: didn't thought to look there...thanks!

Comment: Is there any workaround that I can use in the meantime? I need to control the "finish" as there can be several results to the Lead ID (whether lead is merged or not)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.